# Crear archivo "Nuevo acceso directo a Internet" con extensión (.url) en java?

Tags: java, url

Hola a la comunidad necesito saber como crear un archivo de acceso directo a una pagina web en java.

Como el siguiente ejemplo: (google)

```
https://www.google.com.pe/  ---> "Nuevo acceso directo a Internet"
```

Serie un archivo con extension **.url**

Gracias.

Comment: coloca el codigo y no un enlace.

Comment: Ok lo modifique

Comment: Basicamente, un archivo `*.url` contiene texto en [cierto formato](http://www.lyberty.com/encyc/articles/tech/dot_url_format_-_an_unofficial_guide.html), basta con que lo crees en Java con las APIs para escribir archivos